# parameter of scripts part in package.json for angular2

Tags: angular

I tried angular 2 demo from website [Here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)

In package.json

```
 "scripts": {
       "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
        "lite": "lite-server",
        "tsc": "tsc",
        "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  }
```

[image]

see in command image when project start first line of scripts called and  projects starts normally

but when I removed   this

```
        "lite": "lite-server",
        "tsc": "tsc",
        "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
```

after that projects works normally question comes in mind then what the use of this three line because this command already put in first line

I totally new in angular 2  I tried to learn line by line execution

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works because you execute

```
npm start
```

It will then execute the commands after your 'start' configuration. The removed lines have nothing to do with the npm start.

You could execute them by using

```
npm lite
```

Which will then be startin a lite server, see:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server

In other words. They are start-up parameters. For more info, check this out:
https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts